# Processing Language: for loop elaboration, please

Tags: for-loop

I've just started learning the Processing programming language from the book "Getting Started with Processing".  So far, it has been very intuitive to me until I reached the for loop.

```
size(480, 120);
smooth();
strokeWeight(8);

for (int i = 20; i < 400; i += 60) {
    line(i, 40, i + 60, 80);
}
```

Sure, this example from the book works just fine in the PDE (Processing Development Environment) however, here's what doesn't make sense to me:

The first time through the `for`-loop, it *reads* the first parameter `'int i = 20'` and maybe the second `'i < 400'` however, it appears to ignore entirely the last parameter of `'i +=60'`

Then after that first pass, the `for`-loop appears to totally ignore the first parameter of `'int i = 20'` while reading the other two parameters.

Can someone please help me to understand what is really going on here?

Comment: Just serch for for-loop (doesn´t matter if it is Processing, C, C++, Java, C#, PHP, etc.etc...). There are *many* explanations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this, you need to know how `for`-loop works. See the flowchart:

[image]

Comment: Apparently it was a bad question to ask :(  But thank you @herohuyongtao for being humble enough to give me this excellent explanation instead of just voting it down and giving me lazy, 'I know it all' comments.  However, I learned that lesson the hard way and will make an effort to ask better questions in the future.  I just feel that the net can always use more information.  Who knows, this may now appear at the top of Google search results to answer others' questions about this.  All of you were n00bs once too.  Some forget that.

Comment: @user3513147: Nobody downvoted, and my comment wasn´t meant bad. Just, you would got the anwser faster than anyone can type an answer here, because it´s really basic.

Comment: No, no, not your comment... initially, right after the question, there were 2 down votes and one very negative comment... all of which someone made magically disappear. :)